# Using Redis cluster with Internal and Public IPs

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have a usecase where Redis cluster needs to be deployed over cloud compute server. This cluster should have access from local network as well as internet.

At the time of creating the cluster, I had provided internal IPs of the nodes. When I try to connect it using Jedis, it returns those IPs no matter where I access it from, even if I declare all public IPs at the time of initialisation.

Is there a way to handle both internal and public IPs on redis cluster?

I have already tried `cluster meet <IP> <PORT>`. It simply replaces private IPs with public ones and vice-versa. I need both to work simultaneously.